# Iframe width and heigth won't change

Tags: iframe, responsive-design

This iframe's width and height won't change. I want responsive design. Please help.

Now:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.kadinvekadin.net/mod-burclar.php"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        width="300"
        height="300">
```

Modified 500x500 - not working, still 300x300:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.kadinvekadin.net/mod-burclar.php"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        width="500"
        height="500">
```

Comment: You need to make your iframe responsive for all screens or you just need to display them at 500*500?

Comment: I want responsive design. But this iframe (http://www.kadinvekadin.net/mod-burclar.php) not resizable.Size do not change.How to change width/height?

Comment: This iframe set maximum resize 300x300. For example i want 350x350 but i do not this. @PrasannaAarthi

Comment: i found a solution ,check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516763/delphi-embeddedwb-iframe-height-issue) , hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

for a pure CSS solution you need to wrap your iframe around a container and apply styles to it, for more details please see http://andmag.se/2011/11/responsive-embeds/

Another option is using jquery
please take a loom at https://gist.github.com/aarongustafson/1313517

Try this code,

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <style>
 html,body        {height:100%;}
 .wrapper         {width:80%;height:100%;margin:0 auto;background:#CCC}
 .iframe1        {position:relative;}
 .iframe1 .ratio {display:block;width:100%;height:auto;}
 .iframe1 iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%;}

 </style>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="iframe1">

    <img class="ratio" src="sometransparentimage.jpg"/>
    <iframe src="http://www.kadinvekadin.net/mod-burclar.php" frameborder="0" 

      allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I tried two options too. But still this iframe: http://www.kadinvekadin.net/mod-burclar.php not resizable. Please help.

Comment: Thank you ı tried this code and jquery. "sometransparentimage" is responsive but iframe not responsive. When i resize browser window this iframe do not responsive still. Are there any other ways do responsive this iframe?

Comment: You are having an image of fixed width inside your iframe, you cant resize the image, you can only resize the iframe.. you will be gettibg scroll bars for smaller sizes

Comment: i dont want resize the image already, i want iframe, but iframe do not resize. Can you give me example code which enable resize this iframe? Thank you.

Comment: Set frameborder for the above code and check, i find iframe resizing

Comment: No. i check above code but result fail. frameborder="1", frameborder=2 ... i check but not responsive...